# how can i show different backgrounds in multiple buttons in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I need to show multiple buttons, but each one must have a different background than other buttons, I have been working on it, but I only got to display multiple buttons but with the same background. 
Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="apple.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="370" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <DockPanel Name="dock">
            <UniformGrid Name="gridx" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Rows="3" Columns="3" Height="334"> 
            </UniformGrid>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Also, here is the C# code:

```
namespace apple
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            masterGUI();
        }

    public void masterGUI()
    {
        ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
        IconImage[] ico = null;
        Bitmap[] img = null;
        string[] list = null;
        string[] link = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs", "*.lnk", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        list = new string[link.Length];
        ico = new Icon[link.Length];
        img = new Bitmap[link.Length];
        for (int n = 0; n < link.Length; n++)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
            list[n] = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(link[n]);
            FileToImageIconConverter some = new FileToImageIconConverter(link[n]);
            ImageSource imgSource = some.Icon;
            ib.ImageSource = imgSource;
            newBtn.Background = ib;
            newBtn.Content = list[n];
            gridx.Children.Add(newBtn);
        }  
    }
}
```

}

Any idea? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ImageBrush` needs to be created in the for-loop individually for each item. Otherwise you will end up with the same background for every item.

Also you are approaching this the "wrong" way, in WPF you should use [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [**data templating**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) for this sort of thing instead of imperative looping.

Comment: thank you very much! is there any way to make each button execute a different action?

Comment: @FernandoSantiago: Yes, either create a class which hosts the image and a [command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) and bind them respectively (this is cleaner) or hook up the [`Click` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx) depending on whatever condition.

Comment: @FernandoSantiago: You're welcome. If this answered your question you could [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) it. If you have questions about those things i mentioned please go through the linked articles first and try it, then ask a separate question but if you read them thoroughly it shouldn't be too difficult (even if it takes some time to get used to it).